# How to prevent fetching of images for same input value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Below given is my onclick event handler which is triggered to search images of the movie when I enter the movie name in the search bar, thus the input value here is a movie name. The function used to get the movie images is TopMovies() function through API.

```
const SearchButton =document.querySelector('#search');
const InputValue = document.querySelector('#input_value');

SearchButton.onclick = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const value = InputValue.value;
    console.log(value);
    const newUrl =multi_search + '&query=' +value; 
    function TopMovies(searched_movies){
        const sectionOfMovies = document.createElement('div');
        sectionOfMovies.classList.add('search_movie_section');
        sectionOfMovies.setAttribute('class','search_movie_section')
        searched_movies.map((searched_movie)=>{
            const img= document.createElement('img');
            const a= document.createElement('a');
            img.src= image_url + searched_movie.poster_path;
            a.appendChild(img);
            sectionOfMovies.appendChild(a);
        
        });
        return sectionOfMovies;
    }
 fetch(newUrl) // fetching the images through API
    .then((res)=>res.json())
    .then((movie_data)=>{
        const searched_movies= movie_data.results;
        const Poster_Block = TopMovies(searched_movies);
        topMovies.append(Poster_Block)
        console.log('movies',movie_data);
        InputValue.value='';
    })
    .catch((error)=>{   
        console.log('err',error)
    }) 
}
```

All the above code is dumped into this SearchButton.onclick = function(event)

Now the issue I am facing is that if I search for a movie by clicking on the search button 1st time, I am getting the images for that movie 1 time. if I click on the search button 2nd time. Similarly, if I click on the search button 3rd-time total images are fetched 3 for the same input value. In short, the images are fetched as many times I click on the search button for the same input value.

For eg:- If I search for the movie Lion king and click on the search button 2 times, the images are fetched 2 times. So how can I fetch the movie image one time even though I click on the search button 2 times or more with the same input value "Lion king"?.

How can I stop fetching images multiple times?

**According to me the images are fetched multiple times for the same input value is because I have dumped all my code in `SearchButton.onclick=function(event)` thus images are fetched every time when I click on the search button.**
Help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the button onClick of it and re-enable it after getting a response.
Remember to clear the div element onClick of the 'search' button.
So that the element will only have new results.

Comment: How do I clear the div element onclick of search button?

Comment: Thanks for the idea of clearing div!! , I solved the problem.

Comment: Please don't copy answers,  if your answer resembles the another person answer , mentioned their names. It's just a kind request..

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to disable the button, once you clicked and enable the button once its response status is 200 or something error. Note: clear the HTML for the div before you append, else it will append twice.